# Npgsql with .NET 5.0

Tags: .net, npgsql

I would like if anyone knows how to use **Npgsql** with **.NET 5.0**. Under **.net Framework** (4.8) it is very handy and no problem. But under .NET 5.0 or 6.0, i can not.

**Update** :
Sorry. Here's the problème.

When i try to use the NpgSQL package i face the following exception :

> {"The specified invariant name 'Npgsql' wasn't found in the list of
> registered .NET Data Providers."}

- App.config file (The exact same file works under .NET Framework 4.8) : Failed

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
```

- Directly in the code : Failed as well

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            try
            {
                using (DbConnection connection = CreateDbConnection("Npgsql", "host = localhost; port = 5432; database = MyDatabas; user id = MyUser; password = MyPassword"))
                {
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        connection.Close();
                        label1.Content = "CreateDbConnection Ok";
                    }
                    else
                        label1.Content = "CreateDbConnection Failed";
                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Content = ex.Message;
                return;
            }
        }


        static DbConnection CreateDbConnection(
            string providerName, string connectionString)
        {
            // Assume failure.
            DbConnection connection = null;

            // Create the DbProviderFactory and DbConnection.
            if (connectionString != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    DbProviderFactory factory =
                        DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

                    connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Set the connection to null if it was created.
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection = null;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            // Return the connection.
            return connection;
        }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: What does “I can not” mean? Please describe the actual problem, error, what have you

Comment: Sorry, I uppdated my previous Post.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 5+ (and .NET Core) don't use App.config any more. While you can still access App.config via System.Configuration, DbProviderFactories is no longer automatically populated from it.

If you're just looking to use Npgsql, you can directly instantiate NpgsqlConnection in your code (`new NpgsqlConnection()` instead of `factory.CreateConnection()`). If you're looking to use DbProviderFactories in order to support multiple drivers, you need to pre-register Npgsql's DbProviderFactory at program start, as follows:

```cs
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Npgsql", NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
```

Comment: Man, you deserve my respect.
This aim of this is to upgrade an old project that uses EntityFramework. Everything works fine with the Database so i just want to pick up the data mapping under a new project.

Comment: Hi, thhank you for your help.
It works fine with the App.conf. 
I try to remove it, but get the following error : "No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql'".

Comment: For using the old non-core Entity Framework 6.0, see code-based configuration in [the docs](https://www.npgsql.org/ef6/index.html). This should all work without any App.config.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

The problem was an extension of my previous post  [WPF : Use NpgSQL Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979306/wpf-use-npgsql-entity-framework)

Now with [Shay Rojansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640325/shay-rojansky)'s help, it works fine.

- Configure the App.config file like previous post (link above).
- Add the line below to register the provider before using it.

> DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Npgsql", NpgsqlFactory.Instance);